# How to populate a table (Datatables.js) with a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON object that looks like this

```
data["a01"] = {"field1":"someInfo", "field2":"someInfo"};
data["a02"] = {"field1":"someInfo", "field2":"someInfo"};
data["a03"] = {"field1":"someInfo", "field2":"someInfo"};
```

And I want to populate a table (Datatables.js) 
that I defined like this...

```
   $gbl_tbl_master = $('#op_master_tbl').dataTable({
        "aoColumns": [
            {"sTitle": "Id", "mData": "id", "sDefaultContent": "0"},
            {"sTitle": "total_wrk_h", "mData": "total_wrk_h", "sDefaultContent": "0"},
            {"sTitle": "real_wrk_h", "mData": "real_wrk_h", "sDefaultContent": "0"},
            {"sTitle": "total_bonus", "mData": "total_bonus", "sDefaultContent": "0"},
            {"sTitle": "d_fl", "mData": "d_fl", "sDefaultContent": "0"},
            {"sTitle": "total_uapv_d", "mData": "total_uapv_d", "sDefaultContent": "0"},
            {"sTitle": "p_fl", "mData": "p_fl", "sDefaultContent": "0"},
            {"sTitle": "emp_name", "mData": "emp_name", "sDefaultContent": "0"}]
    });
```

If I set my JSON object ...

```
$gbl_tbl_master.fnClearTable();
$gbl_tbl_master.fnAddData(data);
```

My data does not show, it only shows a unique row with the default values

thanks.

Comment: can you clarify your question better? it seems like you are asking two different questions. also a jsfiddle with more code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A datatable from the framework DataTables.js expects an indexed object, a trick that solved my problem is to use a temporal array like this....

```
tmp = [];
tmp = $.map(data, function(element) { return element; });
$gbl_tbl_master.fnClearTable();
$gbl_tbl_master.fnAddData(tmp);
```